# Select column in a selected range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter my table and copy just a column in my filtered range at a time.

I tried to get column 2 in my range but it returns only the first cell. I also tried .entireColumn, but it returns the entireColumn, not the selected entire column.

```
Sub FillStocks(ByVal myDate As Date, ByVal name As String)

  strDate = Format(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")

  'Filter
  With Sheets("BD_Sheet")
      Set tableRange = .UsedRange

      With tableRange
          Call .AutoFilter(1, strDate)
          Call .AutoFilter(2, name)
      End With

      On Error Resume Next
      Set selectedRange = tableRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      On Error GoTo 0

      With tableRange
          Call .AutoFilter(2)
          Call .AutoFilter(1)
      End With
  End With

  '-----Do something with my range  
  selectedRange.Columns(2).Copy Sheets("MyReport").[A1] 'fail to copy selected values in column B
  selectedRange.Columns(5).Copy Sheets("MyReport").[A2] 'fail to copy selected values in column E      
End Sub
```

Example:

I have a BD in the range "A1:O1000".

After I filtered by date and name, I got Range("$A$1:$O$1,$A$78:$O$172") from selectedRange.Address

I Want to copy column B form my selected range, so Range("B1","B78:BB172").

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing. Do you mean you want to copy only the visible cells in a column *after* filtering the table?

Comment: Sorry about that @Nanashi. I want to copy only the cells in a column in my Range ('selectedRange'). I'll add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectedRange is a multiple area selection - in this instance, the columns property returns columns from only the first area of the range.

Instead, use the intersection of your selectedRange and the entirecolumn your are interested in - for instance with

```
Application.Intersect(selectedRange.columns(2).Entirecolumn,selectedRange)
```

Comment: Smart ideia. Thanks alot!