# Excel VBA to color only certain cells in a selected row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an `Excel VBA` code that will only color certain cells in any given user selected row (`cells A to P`), for example, instead of entire row, which also colors cells with no data, outside my table.

The user needs to look through a list each day and determine if a certain line should be marked green or orange, for example, for later follow-up.

Currently I use this:

```
Selection.EntireRow.Select
  With Selection.Interior
    .Color = 49407
```

But as mentioned that also colors cells outside my data range, and I only want those within a range (`A to P`) to be colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you try to stay away from `Selection`, but if you must have it, then use something like the code below:

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Selection

Range(Cells(Rng.Row, "A"), Cells(Rng.Row, "P")).Interior.Color = 49407
```

Comment: Upvoted, but it's also recommended to stay away from implicit `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` references, as in unqualified `Range` and `Cells` calls ;-)

Comment: @ShaiRado: Are you allowed to contact people directly via this community? I have some other issues I thought you might be able to help me with.

Comment: @DKAbi  you should post a new question with your updated code, this will allow me and other users to assist you

Comment: @ShaiRado: I thought so, so I've updated that question now: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773759/excel-vba-to-import-data-from-other-workbook-in-one-step)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Intersect function

```
Set RangeFixed= Range("A:P")
Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow,RangeFixed).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Color = 49407
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185187/select-column-in-a-selected-range-vba) answer

Comment: shouldn't you use `Set` the Range, as in : `Set RangeFixed= Range("A:P")` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado  Yeah it's fixed, I wrote the answer to quick

Answer (score -1):

"We can use activecell object to color a part of a selected row

```
Dim i as integer    
i=activecell.row  
Range(cells(i,1),cells(i,16)).interior.color=49407
```